# How does Spring Boot provide spring-data-jpa v1.10.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I have a project with a POM which specifies the dependency on spring-data-jpa like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It is not with the version number, however when I run `mvn:dependency:tree` I can see the relevant section like below ...

```
    |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- **org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.3.RELEASE**:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.11.Final:compile
```

... it shows it is with version 1.10.3.RELEASE.

I wonder how does it finally comes with the version number. I looked up, it is neither latest Maven Repository's Spring Data JPA version number nor there is a section in its parent POM defining that dependency. The project POM is like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>${camel-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>${springboot-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>${springboot-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>${springboot-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>${springboot-version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>${springboot-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `spring-data-jpa` is provided by the spring-boot-parent.

You can see the relationship between spring-boot version and `spring-data-jpa` in the [appendix-dependency-versions section of the Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html).

For example, the latest version of Spring Boot will provide version `1.11.9.RELEASE` of `spring-data-jpa`.

In your question you show: `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.3.RELEASE` this suggests that you are using v1.4.x of Spring Boot, the relevant dependency is shown in the [docs for v1.4.1 of Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html):

> **org.springframework.data**    **spring-data-jpa**    `1.10.3.RELEASE`

The relationship between `spring-boot` 1.4.1.RELEASE and `spring-data-jpa` 1.10.3.RELEASE is facilitated by Maven, since Maven follows the relationships defined in Spring Boot's POMs.

From [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-dependency-management) (my **emphasis**):

> Each release of Spring Boot provides a curated list of dependencies that it supports. **In practice, you do not need to provide a version for any of these dependencies in your build configuration, as Spring Boot manages that for you**.
>
> The curated list contains all the spring modules that you can use with Spring Boot as well as a refined list of third party libraries. The list is available as a standard Bills of Materials (spring-boot-dependencies) that can be used with both Maven and Gradle.

So, Spring Boot provides `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` for you which in turn provides `spring-data-jpa` via a dependency on `spring-data-releasetrain`. The precise mechanism for this is:

1. [`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d3c34ee3d1bfd3db4a98678c524e145ef9bca51c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/pom.xml) declares a dependency on `spring-data-jpa`.
2. `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is parented by [`spring-boot-starters`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d3c34ee3d1bfd3db4a98678c524e145ef9bca51c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/pom.xml)
3. `spring-boot-starters` is parented by [`spring-boot-parent`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d3c34ee3d1bfd3db4a98678c524e145ef9bca51c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-parent/pom.xml)
4. `spring-boot-parent` is parented by [`spring-boot-dependencies`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d3c34ee3d1bfd3db4a98678c524e145ef9bca51c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml)
5. `spring-boot-dependencies` imports the `spring-data-releasetrain` POM:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
       <version>${spring-data-releasetrain.version}</version>
       <scope>import</scope>
       <type>pom</type>
   </dependency>
   ```